# Magento2 Admin grid filter computed column

Tags: filter, datagrid, magento2, admin

I have a module, that has a computed column value in its admin grid.
I have added a filter, but it tries to match the filter column/value to a database table column.

I need to catch this filter request, and modify the returned results/collection based on the filter values passed, and perform some custom logic to limit the returned collection/results.

Anyone have a rough idea of how I may achieve this?

EG:
Blog posts have a status column. This column value is populated by using other database held fields such as 'is_published', and 'publish_date'. assigning a value of 'Published', 'Scheduled' or 'Disabled' dynamically.
This shows in the grid fine when not filtering, but when try to filter by one of these values, it returns no results.